# In AHK, how do I say if key pressed is left arrow key

Tags: autohotkey

In AHK, I have the following script:

```
Input, SingleKey, L1, {Left}{Right}{Up}{Down}
if (SingleKey = "{Left}")
  whatever()
```

How do I detect whether the variable "SingleKey" is the left arrow.  The above does not work.

I have tried it with and without the `{Left}{Right}{Up}{Down}`

Is there a better way to get a keypress other than "Input".  I know I can set the left key as a hot key, but that is not what I want:

```
LEFT::whatever()  ;NOT what I want
```

I have also tried:

```
arrowkey := ""
Loop
{
    GetKeystate, state, Left
    if (state = D)
    {
        arrowkey := "left"
        break
    }
}

if (arrowkey = "left")
    whatever()
```

That doesn't do anything either - stays in the loop forever

Comment: If you need to check the state of the key, look at GetKeyState command ( http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/GetKeyState.htm ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got there in the end.  Here is my solution.  Used the GetKeyState function (not GetKeyState command):

```
Loop
{
    Sleep,10

    if (GetKeystate("Left") = 1)
    {
        arrowkey := "left"
        break
    }

    if (GetKeystate("Right") = 1)
    {
        arrowkey := "right"
        break
    }

    if (GetKeystate("Up") = 1)
    {
        arrowkey := "up"
        break
    }

    if (GetKeystate("Down") = 1)
    {
        arrowkey := "down"
        break
    }
}

if (arrowkey = "left")
    whatever()
```

Comment: GetKeyState function and GetKeyState command is practically the same, they do same job, just different return value and usage.

Comment: couldn't get the command version to work - so resorted to the function